# Chromium web browser: user specific /etc/chromium/policies/managed/ policy file

Tags: linux, chrome

I am helping with the set up of a Linux-based Library kiosk thin client solution. We are using Chromium for the web browser, which is launched by a shell script with various command line options. There are a few different use cases e.g. one for accessing the Library catalogue and a few other sites, another for making study room bookings — so we'd want independent URL whitelists. Each use case has its own command line options. Currently all whitelist URLs are stored in the file `/etc/chromium/policies/managed/policy.json`. Ideally I'd like to separate these out i.e. be able to add a command line option like:

```
--managed-policy-file=/home/libcat/.config/chromium-browser/policies/managed/policy-libcat.json
```

...so that each use case has its own white list. However, according to http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches no such command line option exists.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how it might be possible to make Chromium use a different policy file for each use case?

Comment: There's some [documentation on the policy files](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start) but it makes it sound like you can have multiple files that will all be read. Could you possibly have some boolean flags that make only certain policies themselves are activated?

Comment: @Wimateeka Thanks for the suggestion. In the end we simply set up separate VMs, one per use case. It's ~4½ years since I asked this question, and we're now looking at an entirely new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

- Install chromium into [separate chroot environments](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/chroot-with-x-applications/).
- <del>Put first use case file in place, fire up chrome, wait a few seconds for it to load; put second use case file in place ...</del>Won't work; Chromium is watching the directory for changes.